# How to access an array within hash within array within hash within array?

Tags: ruby

I am getting a return value as shown in the picture. I think it has an array wrapped in hash etc.,

how do I access the elements in the innermost network/array ?
something like : p ret[0].hash.array[0].hash.array[0].data I think Iam going wrong dereferencing hashes.

```
p ret[0] works by returning me the hash but dont know how to go beyond that
p (ret[0])['network'] doesnt seem to work i think network is not a key, but how do i access that data structure ?
```

[image: complicated return]

Comment: Like that, if that's the actual structure. It could be `:network` (i.e., a symbol) but we can't see it from here. Also, posting plain text is *much* better than an image.

Comment: I dont know what to write, that why i posted the pic. p ret[0].:network gives syntax error unexpected SYMBEG....

Comment: p ret[0][:network][0][:network][0].data worked!! Thanks. I should have remembered keys are most likely a symbols in ruby.

Comment: just post it as answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your return values is something like this:

```
ret = [{ 'network' => ['something'] }]
```

You can simply:

```
ret[0]['network'] #=> ["something"]
```